# In CakePHP, how do I make data from a table available to all controllers

Tags: cakephp, controller

I have a list of countries and ccodes in a database. I would like to be able to put that data in to an array in the AppController so I can use it via $this->countries in my other controllers. A kind of $this->App->query() if you like. How can I do this please :) Thank you in advance.

Comment: You answered your own question... Put it as a variable on the AppController and it will be available to all controllers that extend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AppController put:

```
public $uses = array('Country'); //list of models
public $countries = $this->Country->find('all');
```

Comment: Green tick when it lets me. Thanks for that, had a brain crash but even though cakephp is new to me I'm really liking it.

Comment: CakePHP is great. Once you learn it, you will have a great time coding your web applications. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just load the countries with a model?

You could use the model in every controller (at least I think).
This should work then: `$this->Country->find('all')`

If you don't want to write this every time you could also move it into a helper.